# ansible replace module is not working as expected

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, ansible-tower, ansible-galaxy

my ansible play book is working for me to uncomment certain lines in a .conf file, but its failing for one particular line its not making any change.

below is my .conf file part.

```
   #<VirtualHost *:443>
      #SSLEnable
   #Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000 includeSubDomains; preload"
   #</VirtualHost>
```

Expected output

---

```
       <VirtualHost *:443>
          SSLEnable
       #Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
        </VirtualHost>
```

below is my play

```
   - name: uncomment virtualhost starting line
     replace:
       path: /opt/conf/httpd.conf
       regexp: '^#(.*<VirtualHost *:443>.*)'
       replace: '\1'
   - name: uncomment virtualhost end line
       replace:
         path: /opt/conf/httpd.conf
         regexp: '^#(.*</VirtualHost>.*)'
         replace: '\1'
```

Here my virtualhost end line is getting uncommented but the startline is not.. can you please guide me here.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

* is a special character in a regular expression, it's a wildcard.

Replace the first task with the following(I have modified only the regexp parameter):

```
   - name: uncomment virtualhost starting line
     replace:
       path: /opt/conf/httpd.conf
       regexp: '^#(.*<VirtualHost \*:443>.*)'
       replace: '\1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the `*` in `*:443`. Otherwise, it will be interpreted as control char for the regexp:

```
regexp: '^#(.*<VirtualHost \*:443>.*)'
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html